# How to return the mean minus each of the integer in a list with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, line, mean, stock

I have a list of sample stock prices for two stocks, IBM and MSFT. After finding the average stock prices of the two stocks, I want to find the mean adjusted stock prices for the two stocks. This is done by subtracting the respective stock prices by their average stock price.

Then, to find the best fit line, I need to find a way to compute (to find m):

**mean_adjusted stock price IBM = m * mean_adjusted stock price MSFT**

However, I am also stuck in returning a list of mean adjusted stock prices for the two stocks.

```
import statistics

def get_best_fit_line(price_IBM, price_MSFT, averagePrice_IBM, averagePrice_MSFT):

    mean_adjusted_IBM = []
    mean_adjusted_MSFT = []
    
    for number in price_IBM:
        mean_adjusted_IBM.append(number - averagePrice_IBM)
        
    return mean_adjusted_IBM
        
    for number2 in price_MSFT:
        mean_adjusted_MSFT.append(number2 - averagePrice_MSFT)
        
    return mean_adjusted_MSFT

price_IBM = [132.45, 130.85, 130.00, 129.55, 130.85, 129.48, 130.51, 130.23, 132.31, 131.78]
averagePrice_IBM = statistics.mean(price_IBM)
    
price_MSFT = [30.95, 30.96, 30.77, 30.45, 30.66, 30.27, 30.07, 30.35, 30.96, 30.86]
averagePrice_MSFT = statistics.mean(price_MSFT)

IBM, MSFT = get_best_fit_line(price_IBM, price_MSFT, averagePrice_IBM, averagePrice_MSFT)


print('The mean adjusted stock price for IBM is ', IBM)
print('The mean adjusted stock price for MSFT is ', MSFT)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First, create a function to average the list of number

```
   def average(lst): 
        return sum(lst) / len(lst)
```

Function, to minus the average to each number in the list

```
def get_append_avg(price_list, average_val):
  mean_adjusted=[]
  for number in price_IBM:
          mean_adjusted.append(number - average_val)
  return mean_adjusted
```

Call each def as below

```
IBM=get_append_avg(average(price_IBM))
MSFT=get_append_avg(average(averagePrice_MSFT ))
```